# Java thread with highest priority

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a sequence of threads (in an ArrayList()) working with their scheduling plan. Then there is another rendering thread that sleeps every 10 seconds (by Thread.sleep(10000)), and every time it wakes, it will block all other threads and render the gameboard. I want to know how to use locks to achieve this.

I tried using a lock surrounding each thread and setting the rendering thread's priority to the highest, but the fps rate is still low. I want the number of gameboards rendered to be around (total elapse time) * (required fps).

Comment: What does "lock surrounding each thread" mean? Can you add a code example to your question? As a rule of thumb, whenever you're writing multi-threaded code, you want to minimize the amount of time that any given thread spends holding a lock. The more time your threads spend holding a lock, the less benefit you will get by using threads.

Comment: Are you asking how to achieve this, or do you really want to ask how to use locks to achieve this? Because if your question really is how to use locks to achieve this then you are asking how to solve an X-Y problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Also: the title talks about thread priority, but there is nothing in the description of the problem that has anything whatsoever to do with thread priority.  So, what is the problem? What have you tried? What did not work? Exactly how did it not work?

Comment: Also: a thread that sleeps every 10 seconds does not make sense. Do you mean a thread that always sleeps and only wakes up once every 10 seconds?  If that is the case, then you have deliberately chosen an incredibly low FPS of 0.01, so I can hardly imagine why and how you should be worrying about restructuring code to make it faster.